# Access Mobile Number from Active Directory in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, active-directory

Can I access mobile number from AD in an Office 365 project using rest api or server side code?

Currently I am able to get information like emailand name from rest api but not mobile number or phone number.

Comment: Is the value available in customers Azure AD?

Comment: Not Azure it is SharePoint Online office365 site.

Comment: Well, in Office 365 the user data is saved in Azure AD... hence the question

Comment: i am not able to login.says " No subscriptions found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution with the help of this [link](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)
here is the complete method

```
function getInformation(userEmailId) {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|" + userEmailId + "'";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },

        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {
            var obj = data.d.UserProfileProperties;
          if(typeof(obj)  != "undefined") {

            obj =  obj.results
            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
                if (obj[key].Key == "WorkPhone") {
                    alert(obj[key].Value);
                }
            });
          }
          else{
            alert('Wrong User');
          }
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```